# PHP - Send Hex With PhpSerial

Tags: php, serial-port, hex, usb, rs485

I am trying to send hexadecimal with php_serial.class.php but cannot.
The message is sent correctly without error, but the component does not react.
I tested it with CoolTerm and it still works.

Did I forget a step?

```
<?php
    include 'PhpSerial.php';
    $serial = new PhpSerial;

    // First we must specify the device. This works on both linux and windows (if
    // your linux serial device is /dev/ttyS0 for COM1, etc)
    $serial->deviceSet("/dev/tty.usbserial");

    // We can change the baud rate, parity, length, stop bits, flow control
    $serial->confBaudRate(19200);
    $serial->confParity("none");
    $serial->confCharacterLength(8);
    $serial->confStopBits(1);
    $serial->confFlowControl("none");

    // Then we need to open it
    $serial->deviceOpen();

    $message = "\x02\x00\x31\x03\x36";
    $serial->sendMessage($message);

    $serial->deviceClose();
```

Answer (score 0):

I also tried like this :

```
<?php
include 'PhpSerial.php';
$serial = new PhpSerial;

// First we must specify the device. This works on both linux and windows (if
// your linux serial device is /dev/ttyS0 for COM1, etc)
$serial->deviceSet("/dev/tty.usbserial");

// We can change the baud rate, parity, length, stop bits, flow control
$serial->confBaudRate(19200);
$serial->confParity("none");
$serial->confCharacterLength(8);
$serial->confStopBits(1);
$serial->confFlowControl("none");

// Then we need to open it
$serial->deviceOpen();

$message = chr(0x02) . chr(0x00) . chr(0x31) . chr(0x03) .  chr(0x36);
$serial->sendMessage($message);

$serial->deviceClose();
```

With a var_dump I get the value 16, but no reaction from my controller ...
I am a little lost, I have verified that the controller received the message. And with the CoolTerm app everything works.